Signature in mexc API - websocket access
I am trying to access websocket user data streams in mexc api. Have read the documentation but still have no luck to connect. I believe I need to create listen key first, but have no luck to make a valid signature. This is my code:
def create_listen_key(api_key, api_secret):
    url = "https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/userDataStream"

    
    timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))

    params = {"please_sign_it": None}
        

    signature = generate_signature(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret, ign_params=params, 
    req_time=timestamp)

    paramsWithSignature = {
        "please_sign_it": None,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "signature": signature
    }

    headers = {
        "X-MEXC-APIKEY": api_key,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=paramsWithSignature)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(response.content)
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to create listen key: {response.text}")

and this is a function for generating signature
def generate_signature(api_key, api_secret, req_time, sign_params=None):
    ic("def generate_signature")

    if sign_params:
        sign_params = urlencode(sign_params, quote_via=quote)
        ic(sign_params)

        to_sign = f"{api_key}{req_time}{sign_params}"
    else:
        to_sign = f"{api_key}{req_time}"

    sign = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return sign

I believe I tried all variants but no matter what i do:
Exception: Failed to create listen key: {"code":700002,"msg":"Signature for this request is not valid."}

If someone can suggest how this should be done would appreciate a lot.

ign_params=params in your generate_signature call is just a typo, or ...?

None of the examples I can see below https://mexcdevelop.github.io/apidocs/spot_v3_en/#signed, appear to include the API key in the signature calculation - but you appear to be doing that?

@C3roe - so do you have an idea how should the generate_signature function look like? UNfortunately I don't see the whole example in docs. I just try to stitch something . . .

It should simply be all the parameters from the query string and/or request body (if you got both, then query string and request body concatenated directly, without an addition & between them), including the timestamp parameter.

So how does that differ from the function I have now?

You've included the API key, and you are treating the timestamp separately, instead of just as part of "all" the parameters. {req_time} inserts just the value, the parameter name is missing. If your data is foo=bar and baz=xyz, with the current timestamp being 123 - then you are creating 123foo=bar&baz=xyz - whereas it should be timestamp=123&foo=bar&baz=xyz

Hey mister. Thank you so much for your answer. But could you please be so kind and provide the function for me. I am struggling with understanding what should I fix.

@C3roe - thank you a lot. I got it to work with correcting this line in generate_signature:
to_sign = f"timestamp={req_time}&{sign_params}"
and also removing params parameter in a function at all. I got those from pymexc, but it works now. Thank you again.
